# Can native apps be installed on chromebooks?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'd like my chrome application to communicate with my chrome extension running on chromebook.  I think that there is no way of passing messages between the two but I'm not absolutely sure about it.
I think that I could accomplish the above by having a native app that would act as a go-between.  According to the docs, chrome apps and extensions can exchange messages with native apps.
However, it is not clear to me if native apps can be installed on chromebooks where OS is kind of 'hidden' from end users.

Could someone please shed some light on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need native apps to communicate between an app and extension. You can simply use [runtime.onMessageExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) instead of runtime.onMessage for listening to messages from other apps/extensions.
For sending message to another app/extion, specify the extension id as the first argument while calling the method [runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage).